# how to calculate total payment in textView which is retrieve from Php server

Tags: android, mysql

```
[{"id":"1","payment":"25414"},{"id":"2","payment":"698547"},{"id":"3","payment":"98745"},{"id":"4","payment":"9857485"},{"id":"5","payment":"365214"},{"id":"6","payment":"10"},{"id":"7","payment":"965845"},{"id":"8","payment":"654123"},{"id":"9","payment":"654123"},{"id":"10","payment":"365241"}]
```

I want to calculate sum of total payment sum which is retrieve from php i am using JsonArray

```
String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS, ServiceHandler.GET);
            // print the json response in the log

            if (json != null) {
                try {

                    paymentResult = new JSONArray(json);


                   int tmp = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < paymentResult.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = paymentResult.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        Log.d("id", id);

                        String payment = c.getString(TAG_VAL);
                        Log.d("payment", payment);

                        try{
                            tmp = paymentResult.getJSONObject(i).getInt("payment");

                            count = count+1;
                        }catch (JSONException e){}

  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.count);
            tv.setText(Integer.toString (+count));
}
```

But there it count the Array number

what is change to be applied here?

Comment: Try out this one `tmp = paymentResult.getJSONObject(i).getString("payment");
count += Double.parseDouble(tmp);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this :

       paymentResult = new JSONArray(json);
int tmp = 0;
int sum = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < paymentResult.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject c = paymentResult.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            Log.d("id", id);

                            String payment = c.getString(TAG_VAL);
                            Log.d("payment", payment);
                            temp = Integer.parseInt(payment);
                            sum = sum+temp;
}// loop end
            ... // sum is your total payment
```